# Test Lombok's @UtilityClass auto-generated code

Tags: java, testing, junit, lombok

I have a class that's annotated with `@UtilityClass` like this

```
@UtilityClass
public class myUtilClass {
...
}
```

JaCoCo doesn't give me full coverage for this class because of the auto-generated code created by the annotation `@UtilityClass` .
Ideally, I do not want to change any config files to ignore auto-gen code. How can this code be tested?

Answer (score 5):

Just write this unit test to ensure your class cannot be instantiated because of @UtilityClass annotation. Then, coverage will be OK.

```java
@Test
  void test_cannot_instantiate() {
    assertThrows(InvocationTargetException.class, () -> {
      var constructor = YOUR_CLASS_NAME.class.getDeclaredConstructor();
      assertTrue(Modifier.isPrivate(constructor.getModifiers()));
      constructor.setAccessible(true);
      constructor.newInstance();
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

The only "coverable" code that is generated by `@UtilityClass` is in the constructor:

```java
private MyUtilClass() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("This is a utility class and cannot be instantiated");
}
```

As this is a `private` constructor that never should be called, you cannot test it regularly.

If you really want to call it, you can do it with some ugly reflective code:

```java
Constructor<MyUtilClass> constructor;
constructor = MyUtilClass.class.getDeclaredConstructor();
constructor.setAccessible(true);
constructor.newInstance();
```

But you should not do this just for the sake of coverage. Having a high coverage is generally a good idea, but not if you have to sacrifice good testing standards.

I suggest you advice JaCoCo to ignore Lombok's code by adding this line to your `lombok.config` file:

```
lombok.addLombokGeneratedAnnotation = true
```

You don't have to configure this for your whole project. If you put this file only into the package of `MyUtilClass`, JaCoCo will only ignore generated code in this package.